# ruby date format from date A to date B

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I just wonder how the date period can be written in Ruby?

```
date_a = Time.at() # <= new
date_b = Time.at() # <= old
```

I'd love to have something like:
`September 1 - 30, 2016`

Also it needs to be considered the year.
 (Ex. if it's in January,

It should be `December 25 2016 - January 25 2017`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
def format_dates(*dates)
  date1, date2 = dates.sort
  return "#{date1.strftime("%B %d %Y")} if date1 == date2

  if date1.year == date2.year
    if date1.month == date2.month
      "#{date1.strftime("%B")} #{date1.day} - #{date2.day}, #{date1.year}"
    else
      "#{date1.strftime("%B %d")} - #{date2.strftime("%B %d")}, #{date1.year}"
    end
  else
    "#{date1.strftime("%B %d %Y")} - #{date2.strftime("%B %d %Y")}"
  end
end

p format_dates(Date.parse('25/12/2016'), Date.parse('25/01/2017')) 
# => "December 25 2016 - January 25 2017"
p format_dates(Date.parse('25/12/2016'), Date.parse('25/01/2016')) 
# => "January 25 - December 25, 2016"
```

Comment: I don't recall ever seeing "January 25 - December 25, 2016". I think there are only two cases: same month and year or not the same month and year. The modification would be trivial, of course. Upvoted.